# Convert php array to key=value

Tags: php, html, arrays, function, yii

Is there php function to convert `Array` to be like `key=value` in html, and if not what's the best practices ?

**Input**

```
$htmlOptions = array('class'=>'container');
```

...

```
<div <?php someFunction($htmlOptions); ?> ></div>
```

**Output**

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Nothing out of the box. You'd have to use a `foreach`

Comment: For your specific example you should look at [CHtml::tag()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#tag-detail)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fine:

```
function printAttributes($array) {
    $attrArray = array();
    foreach ($array as $name => $value) {
        $attrArray[] = $name. '="' . $value . '"';
    }

    return join(' ', $attrArray);
}

// (...)

$htmlOptions = array('class'=>'container');
```

And then in **HTML**:

```
<div <?= printAttributes($htmlOptions); ?>></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can iterate through the array like this

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
   echo "This is the key : " . $key . "<br />This is the value : " . $value;
}
```

This way you'll get both, the array keys and the values.

Answer (score 1):

Something simpler using a `foreach`

```
<?php
$htmlOptions = array('class'=>'container');
foreach($htmlOptions as $k=>$v)
{
    echo "<div $k='$v'></div>";
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
<div class='container'></div>
```